# Can anyone please advise a better way of switching between WPF windows?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class that correctly handles switching between WPF windows as required and intended. However I can't help thinking there must be a better way to do this. Can anyone can share a better solution?

Those are parts of xaml code, enabling passing a parameter to the class methods. The buttons are loaded via a window template used by multiple windows from a xaml resources file, hence they are not accessible from individual windows.

```
xmlns:sw="cld-namespace:Project1.Behaviour"

<sw:ButtonHandlers x:Key="buttonAction"></sw:ButtonHandlers>

<Button x:Name="btnWin2" Content="CLICK ME" Style="{DynamicResource controlSet}" Command="{StaticResource buttonAction}" CommandParameter="window2"/>
```

And a ButtonHandlers class. If a window is already hidden in background it is brought to view, and current window is hidden. If a window has not yet been opened, a new instance of that window is created, opened and current window is hidden. The reason for this is that users will frequently switch between windows and some of the user set content in each window will need to be preserved.

```
public class ButtonHandlers : ICommand
{
    private Window newWin;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Window currWin = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.IsActive);
        bool winFound = false;

        foreach (Window foundWindow in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (foundWindow.Name.ToString().Equals(parameter.ToString()) && currWin.Name != foundWindow.Name)
            {
                foundWindow.Show();
                currWin.Hide();
                winFound = true;
                break;

            }
        }

        if (!winFound)
        {

            if (parameter.ToString() == "window1" && currWin.Name != "window1")
            {
                newWin = new window1 { Name = "window1", Title = "WINDOW 1" };
            }
            else if (parameter.ToString() == "window2" && currWin.Name != "window2")
            {
                newWin = new window2 { Name = "window2", Title = "WINDOW 2" };
            }
            else if (parameter.ToString() == "window3" && currWin.Name != "window3")
            {
                newWin = new window3 { Name = "window3", Title = "WINDOW 3" };
            }
            else if (parameter.ToString() == "MainWindow" && currWin.Name != "MainWindow" && currWin.Name != "window")
            {
                App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
                currWin.Hide();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
            newWin.Show();
            currWin.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

The below is an example of simplified Execute method, however if I simply show a window without creating new instance first and accessing that instance later when needed, the content of previously hidden windows does not keep. Any ideas how I could modify the below method without declaring all the conditions using if else statement as shown above so the user content in each window is kept?

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Window currWin = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.IsActive);
        Type t = Type.GetType("Project1." + parameter.ToString());
        Window newWin = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Window;

        newWin.Show();

        currWin.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that multiple windows are the way to go for your environment? What about tabcontrol or other approaches to show/hide content within a single window?

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is a large enterprise class application, most of the windows have multiple tabs. We previously considered what you are suggesting, however a decision has been made to go with the multi-window approach.

Comment: If the set of possible windows is defined at compile time, you could define an ID per window (`enum` or something else), maintain a lookup `IDictionary` of created windows by ID, have a window factory method based on ID and in your button handler, translate the `parameter` to the requested ID. Separating the translation process of `parameter` to an abstract request format from the window management may improve code maintainability. Dunno how I can approach your question other than that

Comment: Thanks for this, I will look into it and give it a go.